# File download with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm downloading a file to a custom file path like this:

```
let tempFilePath = self.makeTempFilePath()
Alamofire.download(.GET, downloadURL) { temporaryURL, response in
    return tempFilePath
}
```

How do I know when the download is complete and the success/failure status? I tried `responseData` closure but `result` parameter always appears as "failure".

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can do is use the [Downloading a File w/Progress](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#downloading-a-file-wprogress) explained in the documentation of Alamofire like the following:

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/stream/100", destination: destination)
     .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
         print(totalBytesRead)

         // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
         // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) {
             print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead)")
         }
     }
     .responseData { response in
         print(response)
     }
```

With the above code you can know the `totalBytesExpectedToRead` and the `totalBytesRead` and in part know the difference between both to check if the file was downloaded or not.

In any case you can use too the [Accessing Resume Data for Failed Downloads](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#accessing-resume-data-for-failed-downloads) explained in the Alamofire doc in any case of failure during the download process.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks. Already tried that. Even when `totalBytesRead` is equal to `totalBytesExpectedToRead` the file is still inaccessible.

Comment: You instead want to use the `response` serializer and check it the `error` is `nil`. If it is, then the download was successful. The `responseData` serializer will ALWAYS fail in a success case since the `data` returned from the session delegate will be `nil`. The data is written into the file, not into memory. Also, the documentation in the README for this has been updated.